# How to terminate an inheritible process gracefully

Tags: winapi, createprocess

In order to hoop the stdout of a console application, my process manager start the console application using CreateProcess with bInheritHandles to be true, everything works except that when my process manager was closed but the console application was still alive, if try to restart my process manager, Windows will report error that the port was in used (my process manager open a port to play the service role), and if i use TCPView to check the port status, i found my process manager seems to be still “alive”, the PID was still there but it could not be found in Task Manager, the port was listed in the TCPView but could not be found via NETSTAT command — Windows failed to terminate my process manager due to the inherited handles of the console application, if i need to restart my process manager, i have to kill the console application first.

Is there any way to terminate my process manager gracefully even when the inherited console application still alive?

Comment: you can include your process to job with `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE` . when your process exit - job handle will be closed and all childs will be terminated. more correct way of course synchronize with child - send some command to it for exit, when you want exit

Comment: @RbMm Actually, I am not target to close the console application but want to keep it alive and close the process manager without the above mentioned limitation